# My Android App doesn't open via Link allthough my manifest should instruct it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I have an adroid app, which should open itself above a link like

https://example.com/copyPOI/?ID=613a558o3f8ba

My android manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="false">

    <activity android:name=".Help" />
    <activity android:name=".Orte" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="example.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/copyPOI/" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/copyPOI/" />
            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="example.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/copyPOI/" />

            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/copyPOI/" />                

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And my mainactivity is about:

```
    // Get the intent that started this activity
// Falls die App über einen Link aufgerufen wurde, wird dieser hier verarbeitet
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Uri data = intent.getData();
        if (data != null) {     // bei null wurde die App ganz normal über den Launcher aufgerufen
            // Log-Ausgabe für Debugging-Zwecke hinzufügen
            Log.d("MainActivity", "App opened with link. URI: " + data);

            // Eintrag des zu kopierenden Links in die db
            copyLink(data);
        } else {
            // Log-Ausgabe für Debugging-Zwecke hinzufügen
            Log.d("MainActivity", "App opened without link.");

            make_refresh();
        }
```

But instead of opening my App, my Brouwser gets that link and want to open it.

Does anybody see, whats going wrong here?
I use android 14.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It happens due to the [behavior changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-all#web-intent-resolution) in Android 12.

For your *test* case, it looks like [manual verification](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks#manual-verification) is the easiest way to test how it works. But if you need this logic for production and own your custom domain, you'll need to [add App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links#add-app-links)

Comment: First of all, thanks for your fast support....I'll have to proof that, but it looks good, what you wrote. Thanks very much!